# Expanding TableViewCell using IB

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a table that has 2 sections. Each section(cell) will have content that includes a header, image and a label.

I would like to set this out in the IB.

I would then like to have something so that when my app loads, only the header is visible in each cell (say 50 point size).

When the user clicks the cell, the cell animates and expands to it's full size (say 400 points). When the user clicks again, it contracts back to 50 points.

I've seen tutorials that show how to create this functionality but they seems to programatically do everything. I would like to lay everything out in my storyboard and then just set the contracted and expanding sizes via the code.

Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason all the examples you have seen show how to accomplish the task programatically: you can't do it in IB.